# Bash Script Results file has exceeded

Tags: bash

Hello i try to create bash function search videos file in folder and if find file size bigger then 32mb show msg file has exceeded 32MB in size
help me to complete

my code

```
RESULTS_SIZE=$(find /folder/ -maxdepth 1 -iregex ".*\.\(mov\|mpeg\|wav\|mp4\|avi\|mpg\|flv\|WMV\|AVI\|mkv\)" -exec stat -c %s "{}" \;)
if [ "$RESULTS_SIZE" -gt 32768 ]
then

    echo "Results file has exceeded 32MB in size." exit 1;

fi
```

Comment: RESULTS_SIZE is not an integer, it is a multiline variable with each output of `stat` for each video. You cannot compare it with a number.

Comment: If you want to iterate in bash over files you don't use `find` which processes them all in one pass. You should use a loop. Will expand my answer…

Comment: i need this function for run two command if file bigger 32mb move file to bigfilesize folder else move file to smole size folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use the `-size` switch of `find`, with `-` prefix for size below N, `+` for size over N, and `b,k,M,G` suffixes for bites,kilobytes, Megabytes, or Gigabytes:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -iregex "the_regex" -size +32M -printf "Viseo over 32 MB (size %s): %h/%f"
```

If you want it in bash you could do:

```
for current_file in *.mov *.mpeg *.wav *.mp4 *.avi *.mpg *.flv *.WMV *.AVI *.mkv
do
   if test "$(stat -c %s "$current_file")" -gt 32000000
   then
      echo file size over 32MB: "$current_file"
      mv "$current_file" "~/my_big/file_folder/"
   else
      mv "$current_file" "~/my_small/file_folder/"
   fi
done
```

Comment: yes but how to msg {$file} Results file has exceeded 32MB in size

Comment: What do you want exactly? Find videos over 32M?

Comment: yes if video file over 32mb show msg this video file over 32mb

Comment: @Hemang: No need to overcomplicate things in Bash here, use `printf` builtin from find.

Comment: i need this function for run two command if file bigger 32mb move file to bigfilesize folder else move file to smole size folder